# jQuery UI Slider Pips: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I'm trying to implement [jQuery UI Slider Pips](http://simeydotme.github.io/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/#getting-started) into my project.

When I include `jquery-ui-slider-pips.js` in a `<script>` tag, I receive the following error in the browser console:

[image]

> **Note:** The notice above `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` may be related. It's the CSS file required for the plugin.

​
I've taken a look at the error in `jquery-ui-slider-pips.js`:

[image]

​
As you can see, it looks like the HTML for my page is inside `jquery-ui-slider-pips.js` for some reason. I've opened `jquery-ui-slider-pips.js` in my text-editor to make sure everything is okay, and it's definitely the javaScript file I [downloaded from the docs](http://simeydotme.github.io/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/#getting-started).

I've also tried removing the characters from the script tag multiple times, so that it looks like this, and I still received the same error, which is very strange:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-ui-slider-pips.j"></script> // 1
<script src="assets/js/jquery-ui-slider-"></script> // 2
<script src="assets/js"></script> // 3
```

When I remove the script tag entirely, I do not receive this error. I have no problems with any other `<script>` tag in my entire document.

Here's the order of all my `<link>` and `<script>` tags, in order:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800,300'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="assets/css/style.css" />
<link async rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="assets/images/favicon.png"/>
<script async src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- ParsleyJS & ShareThis -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ws.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script async type="text/javascript">
    window.ParsleyConfig = window.ParsleyConfig || {};
    window.ParsleyConfig.validators = window.ParsleyConfig.validators || {};
    window.ParsleyConfig.validators.date = {
        fn: function (value) {
            return /^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/.test(value);
        },
        priority: 256
    };
</script>
<script async src="assets/js/parsley.min.js"></script>
<script async type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "removedForDemonstration", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});</script>
<!-- jQuery Slider, UI & jQuery Slider Pip -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/jquery-ui-slider-pips.css">
<script src="assets/js/jquery-ui-slider-pips.js"></script>
```

Comment: you have multiple versions of jQuery included.

Comment: @Akki619 removing the second script doesn't fix the issue

Comment: just nitpicking can you close the link tag when you have included css file for jquery-ui-slider-pips.css

Comment: @Akki619 That didn't do anything

Comment: did you download that file directly from the github repo? please make sure it's actually a js file, and not html. Also it seems from yoru screenshot the `.js`is not really a `.js`as it should not have a `<doctype>` :/